# How to list files page wise in linux?

Tags: linux, ls

How to list files page wise in linux? When I list files using `ls -la` or `ls -lt`, the result is scrolling down to the last page and I am unable to view the beginning.

Comment: Pipe the command to more, i.e. `ls -la | more`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pipe into `less` or `more`:

```
ls -la | less
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using `less` rather than `more`

`less` has the ability to scroll backwards and has other add-on features.

`more` is an old utility just used to show more content. Some guy created `less` as an answer to `more` hence the opposite name.